# What are the things we need to revert if the order was returned - magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, orders, sales-order, sales

I created **return & cancel** option in **customer account page**. What are the things we need to revert? If the customer return the order After successful checkout process.

I doubt may be it still present in sales report or somewhere else.

e.g

`Customers buy 5 products (checkout process completed), after that they return one product. I am expecting all the sales report in admin have 4 not 5`.

> **note:** This question have raised based on my doubt. I want to make sure about admin reports don't have any invalid data.